# Does upvoting negate downvotes cast with insufficient rep?

Tags: support, voting

When I downvote a question/answer and reverse this by upvoting (or vice-versa), the first vote is obviously not applied.

Due to the fact that votes cast with insufficient rep are stored in a different table, are they still "negated" when voting into the other direction with enough rep to make the vote count?

Comment: No, the feedback given by users <15 rep is not interfering with votes cast. They are different things (hence the different names: feedback vs votes)

Comment: How can I then "negate" unintentionally cast downvotes?

Comment: You can't. Feedback is not votes.

Comment: You can't, but it doesn't really matter, not many people ever see that feedback

Answer (score 3):

If you lack the amount of rep needed to downvote, the score will not change nor will your downvote be even be used as a downvote (i.e no -1 rep for downvoting an answer, OP doesn't lose 2 rep). Your vote will be sent as feedback instead. You can though, downvote on that post again when you reach the rep minimum for downvoting.

Since you never really voted, you can't reversed what you never did previously. To *undo* the downvote, no.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you didn't answer to my main point. Can a "negative feedback" (due to downvoting without enough rep) be reversed in any way?

Comment: @Artery See my edit

Comment: The "negative feedback" is not worth a score, so it cannot be reversed, because it's not worth anything.  Doesn't count against or for any answer/question.